# How to trigger a storyboard on property changed

Tags: wpf, storyboard, datatrigger

I would like to have a storyboard started, whenever the value of `MyCounter`changes.
With a `DataTrigger` I only can trigger on a specific value.

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyCounter}" Value="Doesn't matter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource myStoryboard}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an EventTrigger with the TargetUpdated event to trigger the storyboard instead of a DataTrigger. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198077/wpf-fire-datatrigger-when-property-changes-regardless-of-new-value) for an example.

Comment: This seems to be unavailable for UWP.