# Evaluate Multibinding when a specific property changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multibinding

I have a MultiBinding that looks like this:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
    <Binding Path="Object1.Object2.MyObject" />
    <Binding Path="Object1.Object2.MyCollection[1]" />
    <Binding Path="MyBoolean" />
</MultiBinding>
```

I only want to evaluate this MultiBinding (and thus call MyConverter.Convert()) when MyObject changes. I'm aware that I could set the MultiBinding's UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit, but considering that Object1 and Object2 are regularly reassigned, I'd have to wire up a lot of PropertyChanged events in the code behind. Is it possible to achieve this in XAML?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What happens if you set the other 2 bindings (mycollection and Myboolean) to `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`?

Comment: I thought you had cracked it there, but sadly I get an error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot set UpdateSourceTrigger on inner Binding of MultiBinding. Only the default Immediate UpdateSourceTrigger is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `DataContext` of your hosting control to that of `Object2`.  Then you can bind to `MyObject` directly.  Does this help?  Of course, this still means changes to `MyCollection` and `MyBoolean` will also trigger the `MultiBinding` re-evaluation.

It would also help if you provided the context in which you're using your `MultiBinding` (i.e. is this returning text for a `TextBlock`?

EDIT:

In response to your comment, perhaps there's a different way.  I assume your 3 multi-bound properties have individual PropertyChanged events.  If your application allows, perhaps you could move those events out of the `MyCollection` and `MyBoolean` properties and into the `MyObject` property.  For example:

```
public object MyObject
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        ...
        OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");
        OnPropertyChanged("MyCollection");
        OnPropertyChanged("MyBoolean");
    }
}
```

Now I know this is a bit of a hack but this would trigger the `MultiBinding` only on change of `MyObject`.

EDIT #2:

Another option would be adding a `EventTrigger` to the hosting control, for example:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MyObject.TargetUpdated">
   <Setter TargetName="yourCheckBox" Property="Value">
       <Setter.Binding>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
               <Binding Path="MyObject" />
               <Binding Path="MyCollection" />
               <Binding Path="MyBoolean" />
           </MultiBinding>
       </Setter.Binding>
   </Setter>                
</EventTrigger>
```

Only catch here would be to make sure `Mode=TwoWay` on your checkbox binding.

I referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198077/wpf-fire-datatrigger-when-property-changes-regardless-of-new-value).

Comment: Thanks, but changing the DataContext doesn't really make sense - particularly since, as you say, it would not achieve what I'm looking for in this question. The MultiBinding is setting a boolean on a custom control.

Comment: Please see my updates.  Forgive me if the XAML isn't spot on.

Comment: Thanks Alan. The Trigger idea is a good one, although you can't use an EventTrigger for binding to data. I tried a DataTrigger and setting the MultiBinding to UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit but it was still updating after any of the properties changed. I've now solved the issue by altering the design of my app :)