# Interactivity DataTriggers reverse value

Tags: wpf, properties, reset, datatrigger

Is there a way to make an `Interactivity DataTrigger` reset the target`Property` to its previous value when the `DataTrigger` is no longer activated ?

In other words, considering the following code :

```
  (...)xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
  xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"(...)

<SomeElement>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding somePath}" Value="someValue">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="someProperty" 
                                 Value="somePropertyValue"/>
     </ei:DataTrigger>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
</SomeElement>
```

is there a way to avoid having to add a second trigger to reset the property *someProperty* to the value it had before it was set to *somePropertyValue* when the trigger occured ?

Comment: are you storing the default value somewhere in your viewmodel ?

Comment: Why would I ? It's purely a view related value such as `Visibility.Visible`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59589700/19496