# Crash when animating a DataGridRow during a scroll

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to make a DataGridRow's background colour animate itself when its data changes. I have used the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198077/wpf-fire-datatrigger-when-property-changes-regardless-of-new-value) and hooked up an animation to the TargetUpdated event. This animation fires when the data is first loaded, when it scrolls and when the data changes.

My biggest issue is that when I try scrolling by dragging the scrollbar with the mouse I get a crash of the following sort:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot animate 'Background.Color' on an immutable object
```

When I scroll using the arrow buttons there's no crash. If I reach the bottom of the list and only then start dragging the scrollbar with the mouse, there's no crash.

Can anyone advise as to why this crash is happening? My best guess based on other reading is that there are several animations running for a single element concurrently because the animation is triggered by scrolling (maybe due to element resuse and contentdata switching?). There's certainly nothing in the code explicitly binding to the background color.

A related issue I have is that I only want the animation to trigger when the data actually changes - not when I scroll.

I apologise that I cannot post a copy of my code. My company's policies make that problematic. Here's a paraphrase (hopefully catching all salient details):

```
<Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation From="Red" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The columns with data I am interested in are similar to the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

Comment: I doubt that it might relate to Virtualizing here. So you can try turning off Virtualizing. The immutable object it means here is actually some `DataGridRow`. For some reason (such as related to performance), it is protected (like as it's put in read-only mode). I'm not sure about this suggestion but it's worth trying. a DependencyObject also has a readonly property called `IsSealed`, maybe it's `true` for such DataGridRows.